# Grab id of a form that has a child input with a name="id"

Tags: javascript, forms, input

So I've run into a strange issue...
I want to grab the id of a form say:

```
<form id="test">
    <input name="id" type="hidden" value/>
</form>
```

But running `document.getElementById("test").id` doesn't return `test` as expected but instead returns the input with the `name="id"`. Anyone know what is going on here?

Here's a fiddle reproducing the issue -> http://jsfiddle.net/jascbbfu/

Comment: why do you need to find the id of the form? you already have it...

Comment: Hm, in your jsfiddle, I noticed that the name of the second test input, is 'id1';  I'll bet you it's interpreting the `.id` as a child element of that name, rather than as an actual attribute of itself.  I'll take a look in jsfiddle

Comment: @Deep I know I have the id, its a proof of concept...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Form control names are used to create named properties of the form that reference the control. So where you have:

```
<form id="test">
  <input name="id">
</form>
```

then the form's *id* property is assigned a reference to the input element named *id*. Form controls should never be given names that are the same as standard form properties, e.g. in the following:

```
<form>
  <input name="submit">
</form>
```

it is impossible to call the form's submit method because *form.submit* references the input, not the method.

As noted in other answers, you can either change the name to something that doesn't clash with standard form properties, or use *getAttribute*. The first solution is preferred as it will also likely lead to more suitable names for the form controls and avoid the use of *getAttribute*.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know you could overwrite attributes like that, pretty hacky ;p I'll probably go with getAttribute or adding custom attributes (e.g. "column=") because I like the idea of mapping my form inputs directly to my database columns.

Answer (score 3):

What happens here is an old artifact from the times when HTML was just getting formalised. It's supposed to sit only under a named collection, but browsers decided to create shortcut access in various random places. Either way, you can read more here: http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/form-access/ And once I am on my desktop I will quote the relevant parts.

Comment: Not about HTML, it's about the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of this line here:

```
<form id="test">
    <input name="id" type="hidden"/>   <!-- HERE -->
</form>
```

The browser thinks that you mean the element with the name of "id" when you say:

```
document.getElementById("test").id // Gets input with the name of "id"
```

Which would be the `<input>` element. Change it to another name other than `id` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

The JS appears to be considering `id` as a child object to the larger form you are considering.  You're looking for the function, `getAttribute`, this works in JSfiddle:

```
alert(document.getElementById("test").getAttribute("id"));
alert(document.getElementById("test2").getAttribute("id"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jascbbfu/3/

Hope that helps!